# Regex to extract value from link

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a String like `file:///android_asset/GwyXUyisyq`. I want to extract the `GwyXUyisyq` from the rest of the string. The value will change in every instance, but the `file:///android_asset/` will always remain fixed. What regex can I use to achieve the same?

Comment: than mean u have some file assest file like zip or rar file and u want to extract  in sdcard

Comment: Why don't you simply take a substring? Eg. result = input_string.substring(21); It will give you the string from G to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regex here :
Just find the last index of `/` and replace everything before it :)

```
    String s = "file:///android_asset/GwyXUyisyq";
    System.out.println(s.replace(s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("/")+1), ""));

O/P :GwyXUyisyq
```

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223838/update-a-tag-name-along-with-its-value